# Visual Studio 2010 toolbox "hides" controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, controls, toolbox

I have a somewhat strange issue with visual studio. Almost every time I create or open a Silverlight project in VS10 groups of controls "disappear" from the toolbox. What I've found out so far is the following:

1. Everytime I start VS10 I have to wait for a minute or so, seeing this message:

> Loading toolbox content from package
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.
>   ToolboxInstallerPackage' {2C298B35-07DA-45F1-96A3-BE55D91C8D7A}

1. The controls that disappears aren't really gone, only invisible, so if I hover over where the controls would normally be, I can see the control name in the tooltip and that way also add it to the XAML.

So, it's still workable, but extremely annoying and it takes time with the loading for some reason, does anyone here have a clue as to what I need to do to fix this issue???

It never occurs when working with ASP.NET, WCF, WPF or WinForms project, only Silverlight.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Do you have any third party add-ins installed?

Comment: I do have Infragistics NetAdvantage installed, yes. But that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try these steps:

- Select `Tools` menu then choose `Toolbox Items`
- Select `Silverlight Components`
- Click on reset and confirm
- Close the window and open again Toolbox View
- Right click on Toolbox and choose reset if items are not displayed.

Comment: I tried for the same however it freezes my visual studio IDE. I tried couple of times and found another solution from [this blog](http://michaelcrump.net/fixing-a-broken-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1) post.